# Inserting items at a specific index in an array - IndexOutOfBounds exception

Tags: java, arrays, oop, indexoutofboundsexception

This feature is supposed to add an element at the selected index and push all other in the array elements down. So, for instance, say I have the following array:

```
[0] = zero
[1] = one
[2] = two
```

if I add another element at index 0 called NEWZERO, the array has to look like this:

```
[0] = NEWZERO
[1] = zero 
[2] = one 
[3] = two
```

but currently I'm getting IndexOutOfBounds exception and it doesn't work, although my array is much bigger than just 3 elements.

P.S. I don't want to use the built-in ArrayList library, which automatically does it for you.

```
public void insert(int i, String s) {

if (array[i] == null) {
    array[i] = s; //Need to add feature that instantly puts the element at the first available spot on the list.
} else { 
    for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++) { //Can't use >= i
        array[j + 1] = array[j]; //THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR.

        if (j == array.length - 1) { 
            break;
        } 
    }
    array[i] = s;
    extendArray(); //If an element is inserted properly, the array becomes array.length + 1
```

I'm not getting the error because there's no space in my array. Even if I have an array with 20 elements, and I'm working with just 3, I still get the OutOfBounds error. Here's my extend array method for when a user runs out of array space.

```
public void extendArray() {
    String[] items2 = new String[items.length + 1];
    for (int j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        items2[j] = items[j];
    }
    items = items2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you initializes an array, it exists from 0 to length-1 values.

in your code

```
for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++) { //Can't use >= i
    array[j + 1] = array[j]; //THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR.
```

you are trying to store values to array[length] that is out of the bounds of the array.

so change the for to

```
for (int j = i; j < array.length - 1; j++) { //Can't use >= i
    array[j + 1] = array[j];
```

Answer (score 1):

When `j` reaches `array.length-1` in the loop, the `array[j + 1]` is out of bounds.

To fix this, change the stopping condition (and get rid of the `break` since it's completely unnecessary):

```
for (int j = i; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
    array[j + 1] = array[j];
}
```

Finally, you might want to replace the entire loop with a single call to [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 1):

When j wil reach at the end  , j+1 will be out of bound and cause arrayIndexoutOfBoundException

**Solution :**

Change the for loop like below

```
for (int j = i; j < array.length - 1; j++) { //Can't use >= i
array[j + 1] = array[j]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have a condition for `j` in the loop, so why do you need to second one? Just use

```
for (int j = i; j < array.length - 1; j++) { //Can't use >= i
    array[j + 1] = array[j]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this fix

```
    for (int j = i; j < array.length - 1; j++) { //Can't use >= i
        array[j + 1] = array[j]; 
    }
```

besides it makes sense to extend the size of the array before inserting the new element